# How to get _ID with SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, adapter, simplecursoradapter, android-adapter

So far I got this

```
  db = new MYDBHelper(this);
    constantsCursor = db.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
            "SELECT _ID, title, value " + "FROM constants ORDER BY title", null);
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, constantsCursor, new String[] { DBHelperMen2.TITLE, DBHelperMen2.VALUE }, new int[] {R.id.item_name, R.id.item_points });
listata = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
listata.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But I have one more field named item_number. I this field I want to write the _ID number

How can I do this ?

```
new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, constantsCursor, new String[] { **???** ,MYDBHelper.TITLE, MYDBHelper.VALUE }, new int[] {**R.id.item_number** , R.id.item_name, R.id.item_points });
```

Here is MYDBHelper

```
public class MYDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db";
    static final String TITLE = "title";
    static final String VALUE = "value";

    public MYDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE constants (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT, value TEXT);");
    }



        @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS constants");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, constantsCursor, new String[] { DBHelperMen2.ID, DBHelperMen2.TITLE, DBHelperMen2.VALUE }, new int[] {R.id.item_number, R.id.item_name, R.id.item_points });
```

Where in DBHelperMen2.ID, the `ID` is the name of the column in your db

This code should work:

```
public class MYDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db";

static final String TABLE_NAME = "constants";
static final String ID = "_id";

static final String TITLE = "title";
static final String VALUE = "value";

public MYDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME + "(" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + TITLE + " TEXT, " + VALUE + " TEXT);");
}



    @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

Comment: I do not have ID field in myDBHelper

Comment: It's always a good idea to declare your primary key as:

_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT

Comment: Where is the `ID` field you want? You are querying "SELECT _ID, title, value " so _ID is in your db

Comment: I post my MYDBHelper class